# Why android snackbar is invisible with mapview?

Tags: android, kotlin, snackbar

I am using map from Yandex MapKit. When user taps on the map I show him search results, add placemark and show snackbar with location name and button.

**Problem**

On my Xiaomi device (Xiaomi Mi 9, android 9) snackbar exists, but it is invisible until some action hasn't been done.

Example:
[Tap on the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJiLr.jpg) [Open apps manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WzgK.jpg) [Open app again by tap in apps manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbUji.jpg)

I can also open search edit (top of the map) and snackbar will be shown.
When snackbar is invisible, it exists: I can tap on the snackbar button radius and button's action will be run!

There isn't any problem when I use android emulator (Google Pixel in different APIs: 23, 28, 29...)

My activity XML:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/placesMapLayout"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".activities.PlacesMapActivity">

<com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView
    android:id="@+id/placesMapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/outlinedTextField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:hint="@null">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/searchEdit"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snackbar creating (Kotlin):

```
val snackbar = Snackbar.make(placesMapLayout, foundObject.name.toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
```

I tried to set layout_height for mapView to get empty place in activity's bottom. And it have worked: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53XeB.jpg). One tap and snackbar is visible! But I don't want to crop my map.

So, is there a problem with mapView and how to solve it?

Comment: check with `findByViewId(android.R.id.content)` instead of `placesMapLayout `

Comment: It didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

```
snackbar.view.post { snackbar.view.requestLayout() }
```

It helped me.